# sorting a JList populated with Strings from a .txt file

Tags: arrays, extract

I have the following problem. I have an array of String within my program. It is populated with Strings from a .txt file. Every position of the array corresponds to a single String containing description, title, price and the path to an image of my products. Is it possible somehow to extract from a position only a certain part of the string, let's say only the path for the image?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a `Product` class for that.
Use for example the method `substring` to get out the parts and create an Array of a new class `Product`, which contains the description, title, price and the image.

```
String s;
String part = s.substring (0, 8);
```